# Adding more than one object to another

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I've been working on my version of the app made in this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/complex-data-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). And I've got question about a connection between two objects. My idea is to add more than one Material to Paczka. I've manage to connect them together but I can add only one Material. So my question is what should I do to be able to connect more than one?

Object Material

```
public class Material
{
    [Key]
    public int PaczkaID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PN { get; set; }
    public string Cert { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }

    public Paczka Paczka { get; set; }
    
}
```

And object Paczka

```
public class Paczka
{
    public int PaczkaID { get; set; }
    public string CRS { get; set; }
    public string WO { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
                
    public Material Material { get; set; }

}
```

Here is how I can add Material to Paczka

```
public class MaterialModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly Pasto.Data.PastoContext _context;

    public MaterialModel(Pasto.Data.PastoContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Paczka Paczka { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Paczka = await _context.Paczkas
            .Include(i => i.Material)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.PaczkaID == id);

        if (Paczka == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Page();
    }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int? id)
    {


        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var paczkaToUpdate = await _context.Paczkas
            .Include(i => i.Material)                
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.PaczkaID == id);

        if (paczkaToUpdate == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Paczka>(
             paczkaToUpdate,
             "Paczka",
              i => i.Material))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(
                paczkaToUpdate.Material?.Name))
            {
                paczkaToUpdate.Material = null;
            }
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
        
        return Page();
    }
            
}
```

And HTML

```
a<form method="post">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <strong>Name</strong>
            </th>
            <th>
                <strong>P/N</strong>
            </th>
            <th>
                <strong>Certificate</strong>
            </th>
            <th>
                <strong>Quantity</strong>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <div class="form-group">
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="Paczka.Material.Name" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="Paczka.Material.PN" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="Paczka.Material.Cert" class="form-control" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input asp-for="Paczka.Material.Qty" class="form-control" />
                </td>


            </tr>
         </tbody>
    </div>
</table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a asp-page="./Index" class="btn btn-danger">Back to List</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want a Pazka to have many materials? If so, can a material belong to different Pazkas?

Comment: Yes, I want Paczka to have many Materials. The material should belong only to one Paczka because I want to create them while creating Paczka.

Answer (score 0):

> I want Paczka to have many Materials. The material should belong only
> to one Paczka because I want to create them while creating Paczka

From your description, the Paczka and Materials should be configured one-to-many relationship. In the Paczka class, use `List` or `ICollection` to define the navigation property (Material), code like this:

```
public class Paczka
{
    public int PaczkaID { get; set; }
    public string CRS { get; set; }
    public string WO { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public List<Material> Material { get; set; }
}
public class Material
{
    [Key]
    public int PaczkaID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PN { get; set; }
    public string Cert { get; set; }
    public string Qty { get; set; }
    //the foreign key
    public int PaczkaForeignKey { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PaczkaForeignKey")]
    public Paczka Paczka { get; set; }

}
```

Then, in the View page, you could use `@for` statement to loop through the Material and display the related data, code like this:

```
@page
@model RazorPageSample.Pages.MaterialModel
@{
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Paczka.PaczkaID" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Paczka.CRS" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Paczka.CRS" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Paczka.CRS" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Paczka.Material.Count; i++)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Paczka.Material[i].PaczkaID" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Paczka.Material[i].PaczkaID" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Paczka.Material[i].PaczkaID" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Paczka.Material[i].Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Paczka.Material[i].Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Paczka.Material[i].Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Paczka.Material[i].Cert" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Paczka.Material[i].Cert" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Paczka.Material[i].Cert" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            }

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in the Post method, get the update value and insert or update the data to database, screenshot like this:

[image]

More detail information about relationships and update related entity, refer the following articles:

[Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1)

[Configuring One To Many Relationships in Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration)

[Update related data - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0)